# Merge xml in PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, merge

i want to merge a PHP DOMDocument in another..

```
//this creates the DOM which will be imported
function element_index(..)
{
$skrit=new DOMDocument();
$skrit->loadXML('<krits:kriti xmlns:krits="http://test.de/krits">..</krits:kriti>');
return $skrit;
}

function crawl_xml($element)
{
//thats the line where to get the result and merge      
$skrit=element_index(..);
$temp3=$skrit->documentElement->cloneNode(true);
$element->appendChild($xpIn->importNode($temp3));
}

//thats how i start the recurisve walking through Nodes
$xpIn = new DOMDocument();
crawl_xml($xpIn->firstChild);
```

The input/output should like this:

```
<!--input-->
<all><one/></all>

<!--input new to add-->
<krits:kriti xmlns:krits="http://test.de/krits">..</krits:kriti>

<!--ouput-->
<all><krits:kriti xmlns:krits="http://test.de/krits">..</krits:kriti><one><krits:kriti xmlns:krits="http://test.de/krits">..</krits:kriti></one></all>
```

maybe importNode might be not a good choice? The cloneNode I used because I hoped to avoid problems with recursive call.. So what i am doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import the whole node sub-tree (and not just the node itself), you need to set *$deep* to **true** in `importNode`:

```
$domDocument->importNode($node, true);
```